# textContent in JavaScript not showing the correct output

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

[On the left is the results from textContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU51F.png)

Just a bit of context from the image. I am trying to manipulate DOM by invoking the textContent to the window everytime the user clicks the button while also logging it in the terminal. However, let's say if I click scissor and then click the rock button quickly after, the textContent resulting from clicking the rock button will not be invoked even though I can see from the terminal that the button has indeed been clicked and logged in the terminal so I need to wait for ~1s every time so the textContent can prints to correct statement. Is there a a way so that I can click the button and the textContent will precisely prints out the desired statement?

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container")

const content = document.createElement('div')
content.classList.add('result')
container.appendChild(content)


const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', playGame));

function computerPlay() {
  let responses = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
  response = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
  return response;
  // console.log(response)
}

function playGame(e) {
  let userScore = 0
  let computerScore = 0
  playerResponse = e.target.className;
  computerSelection = computerPlay()  
  console.log(playerResponse)
  // console.log(computerSelection)
  // for (let i = userScore; i < 5; i++){
    if (playerResponse == 'scissor' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
      // console.log("It's a tie!")
      content.textContent = "You win! Scissor beats paper"
    } else if (playerResponse == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
      userScore++
      // console.log("You win, scissor beats paper")
      content.textContent = "You win! Paper beats rock"
    } else if (playerResponse == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissor") {
      userScore++
      // console.log("You win, rock beats scissor")
      content.textContent = "You win! Rock beats scissor"
    } else if (playerResponse === computerSelection) {
      // console.log("You win, paper beats rock")
      content.textContent = `You both choose ${playerResponse}, it's a tie!`
    } else {
      computerScore++
      // console.log("You lose, try again!")
      content.texContent = "You lose, try again!!"
    }
    
  // }
  // console.log(computerScore)
  // console.log(userScore)
}
```

I'm still new to JS so the code is really messy.

Comment: Just a typo in the last `else` branch: `.texContent` is missing a `t` -> `content.textContent = "You lose, try again!!"` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crb1keu4/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that u only assign a new String value to the content.textContent, but u dont update the DOM node immediately after it.

**Put following code options on the bottom of your playgame() function**

**Adding another message**:
U have to do container.appendChild(content) again if u want to add another message.

**Updating the message**:
U can update the text om the screen easy by editing the innerHTML of the current DOM node for example.

```
document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = content.textContent;
```

Comment: There's no `<div>` in `content` (which is the element with class `result`).

Comment: U didnt provide any html so I have no idea wich element u can select. I suggest u set an element in the html that u can always grab with querySelector :)
Or u can use document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = content.textContent;

Comment: Thanks, should I be putting the 2 statements altogether every time I want the message to be printed out? Or just 2 lines of those at the end of the playgame() function?

Comment: I would go for just the lines at the end of the function :)